# multiple INApp purchase request for different product in tableView

Tags: swift, iphone, in-app-purchase

[multiple in app purchase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfK8v.png)I am working a music player application, the user need to purchase the albums before they start hearing it, I have attached a sample purchase screen. when the user tap it it should move to inApp purchase . The purchase type is non- consumable they need to pay only once.

I am having a table view with list of albums in it, if I purchase the first index album, it is working fine when I move to second index it was stating like already purchased.

I have used SwiftyStoreKit pod for the inappropriate purchase and everything is working as I expected. but I don't know how to handle tableview with n number of cell.

```
   //INAPP purchase swift guy

func getinfo (purchase: RegisterPurchase) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatioManager.NetworkoperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([bundleId + "." + purchase.rawValue]) { (result) in
        NetworkActivityIndicatioManager.NetworkOperationFinished()
        self.showAlert(self.alertForProductRetrievalInfo(result))
    }
}



func purchase(purchase: RegisterPurchase) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatioManager.NetworkoperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleId + "." + purchase.rawValue, atomically: true) { result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatioManager.NetworkOperationFinished()

        if case .success(let purchase) = result {
            let downloads = purchase.transaction.downloads
            if !downloads.isEmpty {
                SwiftyStoreKit.start(downloads)
            }
            // Deliver content from server, then:
            if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
            }
        }

        if let alert = self.alertForPurchaseResult(result) {
            self.showAlert(alert)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code...

Comment: the code is working perfectly , I am asking how should I handle multiple purchase that has to be made in a tableview cell.

Comment: I am having multiple cell in my tableview and if I click second cell it was stating already purchased.

Comment: Have you tried to send the indexPath.row to the function that handles the purchase, so it knows its a different cell which has been tapped?

Comment: let me paste my purchase function

Comment: and the tableview code?

Comment: just use print debugging (to make sure the expected parameters are being sent to your purchase functions when the user taps a cell).

Comment: @AchidFarooq I have not written anything for my tableview, just have used the purchase code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your product type. If you want to make the product purchasable again, you should use **consumable purchase**, NOT non-consumable.

> Non-consumable product can be purchased only once for an iTunes
>   account.

For your case, you can change the product type to consumable, then save this purchase in server and link with the user. This way, you can unlock the album if user purchased before.